# As3 Preloader Browser Compatibility Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader

I have a problem with my as3 preloader. I'm uploading a file in DeviantArt and the file works fine if it is [not on fullscreen](http://sta.sh/02a0l30tkvgp).

But if it is in [fullscreen](http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/202/5/1/flashcard__animals__01__new__by_wllflwrpurpleice-d6efn27.swf), the loader doesn't work. However, this problem only occurs in Google Chrome. It works fine with Firefox and Explorer.

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is the code I'm using

```
stop();
import flash.display.*;
this.stop();
LoadingBar.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, LoadingProgress);
LoadingBar.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadingFinish);

function LoadingProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var pcent:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100;
    LoadingBar.scaleX=pcent/100;
    LoadingInfo.text = int(pcent) + "%";
}
function LoadingFinish(event:Event):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses a different version of Flash player, so it might be a security error.

Try installing the [debug flash player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html#How_can_I_run_debugger_or_alternate_versions_of_Flash_Player_in_Google_Chrome) to get error messages from flash content embeded in Chrome

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for that. I thought it was something wrong with my code. I solved the problem by editing my chrome plug-in settings. This may seem strange, but do you know if there is a way I can tell flash to access or use system plug-in instead of the chrome browser plug-in? Like a code in as3 inside my file.

Comment: You could possibly detect the version of flash player and tell the user it's not compatible, but you can't change it. You might have other code somewhere that is breaking the built in Chrome flash player, it would probably be best to find it since almost all Chrome users are using the default player.